# Issue in running Debug mode in Rules Studio

Tags: jrules

I wrote a technical rule and would like to test this rule in debug mode. I am using JUnit test case for unit testing. i have deployed the ruleset in JUnit test project. I have set break points in technical rule. but while running in debug mode, the control is not stopping at the break points.
I checked the "enable debug" option in archive.xml of the RuleApp project.

Please let me know what are the things i need to take care for testing a ruleset in debug mode.

Thanks in Advance.

Hari

Answer (score 1):

you can run the rules in debug mode yes but you cannot have break points in the conditions
only in actions.
Before using JUnit make sure you can run the ruleset in debug mode using a simple java project for rules.
A workaround to test the conditions is to create some print (log/sysout) functions returning true and just print the condition, one by one.

Hope ti helps